# Getting QT5 to work with the "Create a currency converter phone app"-tutorial

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qml, qt5

I'm trying to get into developing for the ubuntu phone, and I'm following the Create a currency converter phone app tutorial by the letter.

Problem is that when I try to preview the app, I get a small white window with nothing happening. I would have posted a screendump, but I am not allowed by the system yet.

I have researched a bit and read that I need to set the path to the viewer in options->environment->external tools to the path opt/qt5/bin/qmlscene. This I have done.

Unfortunantly, no change. I still cannot get anything, when previewing. Can anyone please help me set it up?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like the easiest way to solve your problem is to add a short-cut to your qlmscene external tool as described in the same tutorial you are following, they suggest to put <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. Now instead of clicking on the play button to preview, after saving your file what you need is to enter the short-cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, and you will see your preview.

Hope It hope you.